# How can I align these input text fields

Tags: html, css, input

I tried putting float: right for textboxes (input text) and it aligned the boxes properly but I texts gets misaligned and the add book button as well. How can i fix it?  Thanks.

[image]

```
<div id="add_div">
    <form method="POST" action="add.php">
        <!--start of form -->
        <label>Enter Author Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="author">
        <br />
        <label>Enter Book Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title">
        <br />
        <label>Enter Year Levels</label>
        <input type="text" name="yrLevel">
        <br />
        <label>Enter ISBN</label>
        <input type="text" name="isbn">
        <br />
        <label></label>
        <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add Book">
        <br />
    </form>
    <!-- end of form -->
</div>
```

My CSS below

```
#add_div{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

input {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to change the display to inline-block instead of floating:

```css
label, input {
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="add_div">
    <form method="POST" action="add.php">
        <!--start of form -->
        <label>Enter Author Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="author">
        <br />
        <label>Enter Book Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title">
        <br />
        <label>Enter Year Levels</label>
        <input type="text" name="yrLevel">
        <br />
        <label>Enter ISBN</label>
        <input type="text" name="isbn">
        <br />
        <label></label>
        <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add Book">
        <br />
    </form>
    <!-- end of form -->
</div>
```

Comment: The speed at which this got answered reminded me of this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: That the threshold to ask is nowadays very low, and too little effort goes to searching for the answer independently before asking here what most likely is a duplicate question.

Comment: Oh that's nothing. You can see questions get 7 or 8 answers in under five minutes when the question is moderately well-written and has a simple, often duplicated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add everything to a table and set border="0" so you can't see it. This will keep everything together since all of the content belongs to the table element.

See Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/100/

```css
label, input {
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="add_div">
<form method="POST" action="add.php"> <!--start of form -->
    <table padding="1" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label> Enter Author Name</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="author">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label> Enter Book Title </label> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="title"> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label> Enter Year Levels </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="yrLevel">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label> Enter ISBN </label>
            </td>
            <td>
                 <input type="text" name="isbn">
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <input type = "submit" name="add" value="Add Book">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>  <br/>
</form> <!-- end of form -->
</div>
```

Comment: I thought we got away from using tables to layout pages about a decade ago.

Answer (score 0):

This may help-

```
input {
        display:inline-block;
        *display: inline;     /* for IE7*/
        zoom:1;              /* for IE7*/
        vertical-align:middle;
    }

label {
    display:inline-block;
    *display: inline;     /* for IE7*/
    zoom:1;              /* for IE7*/
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}
```